# TianoCore UEFI Development Kit build: how to prevent the build process to ignore MS Windows - oriented stuff on Linux

Tags: firmware, uefi

I'm trying to build **UDK2018** on **Ubuntu 17**. The platform build process (the Build base tool) unexpectedly tries to build some MS Windows oriented stuff and fails. How this can be fixed?

Following the documented recommendations, at the first stage I build the "Base Tools":

```
make all -C ${EDK_TOOLS_PATH}
```

Then I run the setup script:

```
edksetup.sh BaseTools
```

This stages are finished with success, also the setup script runs some tests that pass.

On the next stages I try to build the platform:

```
build all -a X64 -t GCC5
```

This last stage fails with the follow error:

> Nt32Pkg/Include/WinNtPeim.h:27:10: fatal error: Common/WinNtInclude.h:
>   No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not specifying any platform to build, so the default platform description file specified in `Conf/target.txt` (initialized from `BaseTools/Conf/target.template` by `edksetup.sh`) is used. That file is `Nt32Pkg/Nt32Pkg.dsc` which describes a Windows-specific platform.

Try adding `-p OvmfPkg/OvmfPkgX64.dsc` on the `build` command line, or edit the config file, to build the version for the QEMU platform.

If you are looking to build a standalone module against a generic platform, either define your own generic build description of specify `-p MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc` and have a look at how `MdeModulePkg/Application/HelloWorld/` is integrated - then additionally add `-m <your module .inf>` on the command line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder what is the expected value for the -p parameter for the target Intel 64 architecture?

Comment: That depends what platform you want to build for. This is firmware - all platforms are different; it is the job of firmware to hide that as much as possible from higher-level software.

Comment: The concept of the "platform" is what I can not understand about the EDK. For instance OvmfPkg/OvmfPkgX64.dsc is a "platform", but in the same time it is a "package" that implements some interface. It implements UEFI for QEMU, so there is a sense to tell the build tool to target that platform (i.e. `-p OvmfPkg/OvmfPkgX64.dsc`). Now, if I target the platform that natively supports UEFI, it seems that there is no much sense to provide dependency to any specific UEFI implementation. But in this case (i.e. not providing "-p" parameter), the build mistakenly assumes Nt32 emulator. What I'm missing?

Comment: In the interest of me not trying to make too many assumptions, can you please clarify what are you expecting to build, and what you are expecting to do with it when you have built it?

Comment: I'm trying to build the UEFI application for the three different platforms: the emulation platform (`-p EmulatorPkg/EmulatorPkg.dsc`), the virtual machine (`-p OvmfPkg/OvmfPkgX64.dsc`) and the bare metal platform. The last one is a real PC that has UEFI Firmware ( [Aptio 4](https://ami.com/en/products/bios-uefi-firmware/aptio-4/) ). I'm able to build the first two targets (there are other problems that I probably would like to discuss in the separate threads), but I'm not able to build the last one.

Comment: A proper UEFI application should not require being built against a specific platform (only against a platform that lists all of the protocols  and provides mappings fort all the libraries the application needs). Can you raise a separate question with the specific issue, and minimal buildable example, for the failing application?

Comment: I totally agree with your statement that "proper UEFI application should not require being built against a specific platform" , but if I'm not specifying any platform to build (no `-p` parameter) how I can avoid the default platform of Nt32Pkg?

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you're asking. Answer updated.

Comment: I had read you updated answer. It certainly makes sense. When you wrote to "have a look at how MdeModulePkg/Application/HelloWorld/ is integrated", you meant to _MdeModulePkg/Application/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.inf_, do you?

Comment: Well, HelloWorld.inf is part of how HelloWorld is integrated :)

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system, try building OVMF.

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/How-to-build-OVMF

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/OVMF

https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/Using-EDK-II-with-Native-GCC